# Twitter Bootstrap Modal submit button to submit and open modal in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have the following Twitter Bootstrap Modal button (haml) - I want to use this button to save my form then open the modal dialog to ask if I want to print it. How Can I make this button perform a submit or save :

```
%a.btn{"data-toggle" => "modal", :href => "#myModal", 
  class: 'btn btn-inverse btn-large',
  :role => "button"} Press to Complete Visit

  #myModal.modal.hide.fade{"aria-hidden" => "true",
 "aria-labelledby" => "myModalLabel", :role => "dialog", :tabindex => "-1"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do an AJAX post and have an endpoint to receive the data.

HTML:

```
%a.btn{class: 'btn btn-inverse btn-large',
  id: 'submit-btn',
  :role => "button"} Press to Complete Visit

  #myModal.modal.hide.fade{"aria-hidden" => "true",
  "aria-labelledby" => "myModalLabel", :role => "dialog", :tabindex => "-1"}
```

Javascript:

```
$('#submit-btn').click(function() { 
  $.ajax({
    type: post,
    url: '/your-end-point',
    data: your_data,
    success: function() {
      $('#myModal').show();
    }
  })
})
```

Rails:

**routes.rb**

```
post 'your_end_point' => 'your_controller#submit'
```

**your_controller.rb**

```
def submit
  # Save form data...
  render :json => 'success'
end
```

Comment: that looks perfect but I am having trouble with the data. I am thinking I have to render a json object but I am not sure how to do that

Comment: I've edited my answer with some Rails code sample. Hope it's clearer now for you.