# bootstrap modal with Simple Form Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, simple-form

I have a sign up form ([Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)):

```
    <%= simple_form_for(User.new, as: 'user', url: registration_path('user'), html: {id: "signup-form"},:remote => true) do |f| %>
              <input name="redirect_to" type="hidden" value="true"/>
              <%= f.input :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "First Name", label: false %>
              <%= f.input :last_name, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Last Name", label: false %>
              <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "E-mail Address" %>
              <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @validatable), placeholder: "Password" %>
              <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true, placeholder: "Password Again" %>
              <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block", data: { target: "#confirm-modal", toggle: "modal", dismiss: "modal" }%>
<% end %>
```

When a user clicks on submit the form should do an Ajax POST  to [Devise::RegistrationsController](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb) create action and then show another modal `data-target="#confirm-modal"`. The issue here is that it is not submitting any post request. Is there a specific configuration with [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) for this ?

Comment: This is one way of doing it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17266384/1438462

Comment: @Cyzanfar: I suggest you to have a look on this tutorial which will guide you to understand how modals works in Rails, so that you can master it : https://richonrails.com/articles/basic-ajax-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: @Cyzanfar, 
Personally never tried to use devise calling it asynchronously. Did you try without `:remote => true` ? If it works, then you need to rewrite `Create method` from `Devise::RegistrationsController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: For posterity's sake, I'm editing this with what fixed the issue.

The issue is from the data parameter being passed into the submit button. Removing it will allow the AJAX request to be sent.

Comment: I don't have any hidden html input tag and `<%= f.button :submit %>` still doesn't POST the form

Comment: I was referring to the redirect_to HTML tag. Can you try removing the data parameter from your submission where it targets the modal and tell me if it's  send the AJAX or not?

Comment: Great. Edited the post to reflect this.